# Gson MalformedJsonException on slash

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, gson

I am trying to deserialize a class with Gson.

This is the class I am trying to deserialize :

```
public class Product {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String expDate;
    public String iconPath;

    public Product(final String id, final String name, final String expDate, final String iconPath) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.expDate = expDate;
        this.iconPath = iconPath;
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }

}
```

And this is the code used :

```
final String serializedProducts = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity).getString("products_" + sectionNumber, null);
if(serializedProducts != null) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    final List<?> deserializedProducts = gson.fromJson(serializedProducts, List.class);
    final List<Product> result = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for(final Object product : deserializedProducts) {
        //System.out.println(product.toString());
        result.add(gson.fromJson(product.toString(), Product.class));
    }
}
```

And this is the output of `System.out.println(...)` :

```
{expDate=4/6/2014, iconPath=/data/data/fr.skyost.fridge/files/images/5000112558265, id=5000112558265, name=Coca-Cola Zéro}

{expDate=4/6/2014, iconPath=/data/data/fr.skyost.fridge/files/images/5000112558265, id=5000112558265, name=Coca-Cola Zéro}

{expDate=4/6/2014, iconPath=/data/data/fr.skyost.fridge/files/images/3564700371107, id=3564700371107, name=Eau minérale}
```

I am having an exception `MalformedJsonException` at line 1, column 12 (the slash).

So how can I proceed to deserialize it ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON requires string values to be quoted (including the keywords). And the name/value separator for JSON is a colon, not equals.

So to be valid JSON the text should be:

```
{"expDate":"4/6/2014", "iconPath":"/data/.../5000112558265", "id":5000112558265, "name":"Coca-Cola Zéro"}
```

Refer to http://json.org for full details.

I just noticed that your `toString` implementation uses GSON to produce ostensibly JSON output, but either that `toString` method is not being used, or GSON has a very mistaken understanding of what constitutes valid JSON. My expectation is that it's surely the former.

I now see the problem, I think, now that I look closer; whatever they are your deserialized objects are not instances of `Product`. So the following code:

```
for(final Object product : deserializedProducts) {
    //System.out.println(product.toString());
    result.add(gson.fromJson(product.toString(), Product.class));
```

does not invoke `Product.toString`, but the `toString` of whatever object `gson.fromJson(serializedProducts, List.class);` produces and adds to the list.

You should add `product.getClass()` to your debug output to prove this. And then you should should investigate how to get actual instances of `Product` created.

Comment: My eyes caught, but you fast replied. +1 for that , correct id: not id=

Comment: @user35736644892: Yes, it amazes me how much HTML/XML has conditioned us to see `name="some value"` as normal and correct. I occasionally wish JSON had followed the ML attribute style instead of the `"name":"some value"` style.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I am on the way but when I use object.toString(), it strips me quotes, why ? When I go to the shared prefs file, quotes are like this &quot :/

Comment: @Skyost: Well, the contract of `toString()` in no way requires any specific encoding, but simply a string representation of the object, typically for logging. So unless the `toString` of the object in question is documented as producing a valid JSON representation of the object, there's no connection.

Comment: @Skyost: As for the "shared prefs", I don't follow. But, anyway, the value you give, `&quot;` (assuming you dropped the semicolon as a typo), is an SGML/HTML/XML entity encoding for a double quote, and clearly unrelated to anything JSON.